# Jquery active class on css3 :after animation scroll to div page

Tags: jquery, css

https://jsfiddle.net/eyhwnsbz/5/

This is a generic scroll to div page where I am trying to get the active state when clicked to be active with the animated bar at the bottom. I used the pseudo ::after to do the animation.

I can achieve this if I did not use the ::after and just used the normal hover and active css the same but was wondering if what I am trying to get is possible.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('nav ul li a').each(function (event) {
            if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 40) {
                $('nav ul li a').not(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really get your question.. @.@

Comment: so sorry I added the wrong js fiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/eyhwnsbz/5/ As you can see here I want to have the active class with the animated red bar to be active  when clicked and scrolling down as well on the different div section

Comment: As I read your question, I don't find any `::after` on your fiddle. Also, I don't find any weird behaviour on your fiddle.. So, what's your problem?

Comment: its there the class .nav a::after .nav li a:hover::after https://jsfiddle.net/eyhwnsbz/5/

Comment: My bad. So now you want the red block to show up when you scroll to specific div? Also I don't see `.active` on your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the content after `header` in side a div `<div id="content">` and give margin-top value to the height of the header. Use `$('header').height()` for getting the height.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content').css('margin-top', $('header').height())
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('nav ul li a').each(function (event) {
            if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - $('header').height()) {
                $('nav ul li a').not(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    }).scroll();
});

// SMOOTH SCROLLING (with negative scroll of 40 for header)

$(function () {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top - $('header').height())
                }, 850);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    background:grey;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:white;
}
header {
    margin-bottom:80px;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
nav {
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#1a1a1a;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
nav ul li a {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-right:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:20px
}
nav ul li a:hover, .active {
    border-bottom:2px solid pink;
}
#div1, #div2 {
    height:1000px;
}
#div1 {
    background:green;
}
#div2 {
    background:red;
}
#div3 {
    background:blue;
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#div1">Div 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#div2">Div 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#div3">Div 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        <section>
            <div id="div1">
                 <h1>This is Dev 1</h1>

            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div id="div2">
                 <h1>This is Dev 1</h1>

            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div id="div3">
                 <h1>This is Dev 1</h1>

            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```